# Question on the definition of the parametrization of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

I have in my lecture notes the following definition about the normal parametrization of a curve in $\Bbb{R}^3$.

> **Definition**. (Normal) Parametrization of a curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector fuction
>   $$\vec{r}:(a,b)\longrightarrow \Bbb{R}^3,\ t\mapsto \vec{r}(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$$
>   where $-\infty \leq a \leq b \leq +\infty$, which has the following properties:
>
> 1. $\vec{r}(t)$ is smooth and at least $C^1$
> 2. $\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt} \neq \vec{0},\ \forall t\in(a,b)$
> 3. $\vec{r}$ must be 1-1 with her image.

Is this definition completely right? I can not understand the property 3. What does this mean? Is there an intuitive way to think about it?

*Thank you in advance and I apologize for my English.*

Answer (score 1):

Being "1-1" means being injective.

However, I don't really understand condition (1): being smooth is much stronger than being just $C^1$...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is 1-1 obligatory, and what intuitively means? 

Also, we know that smooth function is a function that has derivatives of all orders, everywhere in its domain. But $C^1$ means that it has continuous derivatives of 1st order (correct me if I am wrong). So, how smoothness is stronger?

Comment: @Chris Smoothness (having *continuous* derivatives of all orders) is stronger in the sense that it implies being $C^1$. As for being 1-1, some authors put it in the definition, some don't. It really depends what you want to prove with it.

Comment: Ok, I searched it earlier in wikipedia and doesn't write "continuous". Now, for 1-1, I dont understand the phrase "with her image". Is 

$$\vec{r}:I:=(a,b)\longrightarrow \vec{r}(I)$$ 1-1?

Answer (score 1):

By 1-1 ness you are avoiding self-intersections of your map. This for example tells you that the a figure 8 intersecting itself in the center is not counted as a curve according to your definition. *

For (1) the author may have meant "smooth OR at least $C^1$.

Addition: This is quite restrictive as it does not include closed curves, such as a circle. But then again one can define closed curves as those that are injective on the interior of the intervals and are equal at the endpoints.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What does the phrase "1-1 with her image" means? Is that $\vec{r}:I:=(a,b)\longrightarrow \vec{r}(I)$ 1-1?

Comment: Yes, of course a 1-dimensional interval in $R^1$ cannot be mapped smoothly and injectively into 3-d $R^3$. Here image is the curve viewed as a subset of $R^3$. If you think of the curve as an object flying in 3-d, then the image is the trace the curve leaves. 1-1 means never hitting its own trace again.

Comment: So, for 3. can we say only that the fuction $f:I \longrightarrow \vec{r}(I)$ is injective?